# Is it possible to use MKLocalSearch to find all nearby businesses?

Tags: ios, location

In order to avoid the API limits of foursquare or one of the other local search providers, I would like to use MKLocalSearch from iOS 6.1. The following code:

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *localSearchRequest = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
MKCoordinateRegion localSearchRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([theLocationChange.latitude floatValue], [theLocationChange.longitude floatValue]), 500.0f, 500.0f);
localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurants";
localSearchRequest.region = localSearchRegion;
MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:localSearchRequest];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog([error localizedDescription]);
    }
    for (MKMapItem* mapItem in response.mapItems)
    {
        NSLog(@"mapitem name is: %@",mapItem.name);
    }

}];
```

will correctly fetch and display restaurants near the specified location. If I change `localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery` to "hotels", it will fetch and display hotels. The same applies for "hospitals", "bars", etc. If, however, I try an empty string, or " ", "*", or "?" for `localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery`, it returns no results.

If I use the foursquare API and send it a location, I can easily get back a list of *venues* that includes local businesses of all types. Is there a way to use MKLocalSearch to return all *venues* or local businesses?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer... did you find anything about it?

Comment: No, as far as I know it's not possible. I filed a bug report with Apple requesting they add this feature and it was marked as a duplicate of #14152587. I am still using foursquare, and we are looking at setting up a server to cache foursquare responses to help with the rate limit.

Comment: Thanks... I'm using foursquares venue search too at the moment... so we need to stick to it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation says that localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery to be considered as natural Language query which means, you can type in anything and get the related results to your query. But Apples Maps database may not be returning the values as you expect.